Mistake in my reasoning in mathematical induction
I was trying to check if equation
$$ 30n<2^n+110$$
holds $(\forall\; n\in N)$ using and induction. However, according to my solution, the equation holds. However, I checked the case for n = 5 and n = 6 and it turned out that it does not hold.
I would like to ask you to point out the mistake in my reasoning
My solution:
1.) I'm checking if equation holds for $n=1$
$$ 30 < 2+110=112$$
Ok it holds.
2.) Now I'm assume that $30n<2^n+110$ holds.
Now I'm trying to prove that  $30(n+1)<2^{n+1}+110$ holds.
So using the induction step I received a sequence of inequalities :
$$ 30(n+1)=30n+30<2^n+110+30=$$
$$ = 2^{n+1}+110+30-2^n<2^{n+1}+110,$$
And now we can see that last equation
$$ 2^{n+1}+110+30-2^n<2^{n+1}+110$$
holds if
$$ 30<2^n$$
So the equation holds if
$$ n\geq 5$$
Then, since the inequality holds for $n\geq 5$ at the end I check if equation holds for $n<5$. So:
For $ n=2$ we have $ 60<4+110=114$. OK
For $ n=3$ we have $ 90<8+110=118$. OK
For $ n=4$ we have $ 120<16+110=126$. OK
So my calculations show that $ \forall n\in N$ equation holds.
However I also checked  the results for $n=5$ and $n=6$
but
For $ n=5$ we have $ 150 \nless32+110=142$ NOT OK
For $ n=6$ we have $ 180 \nless 64+110 = 174$ NOT OK
Then it seems to me that there is a mistake somewhere in my reasoning. I don't think it's a calculation issue because I checked it several times.
I would like to ask you to point out this mistake.
Thank you in advance.

The step is correct for $n\ge5$, base - not

The induction step works  for $n\ge 5$, but the base case has to be verified for some $n\ge 5$, and not for $n=2,3,4$. But $n=7$ works.

Let $P(n)$ be the desired statement. If I have followed the calculation.  You proved that "$P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ if $n≥5$".  Alas, $P(5)$ is false so this tells you nothing about $P(6)$.  And  $P(6)$ is false so this tells us nothing about $P(7)$, but $P(7)$ is true, so from that point on you are good.

Main idea of induction is to have base step and chain step, starting from base step.

@DietrichBurde So, do I understand correctly that if my calculation showed that it holds if $n\geq 5$ does this mean that I should go back to step 1.) again to check whether the equation holds for $n=5$ and then use induction step for $n+1$ ?

Most of your MathJax is large

I think I realized my mistake. Thank you for your help.

Good demonstration that the base step is important. A proof by induction works only if the statement is true for the step $n$ before step $n+1$. You already demonstrated, that your proof works, only if $n\ge 5$. So, firstly your base step has to be at least $5$ and secondly, your statement has to be true for your base step, such that each step after your base step holds true.
For $n=7$ you find
$$30\cdot 7=210<238= 128+110=2^7+110$$
Suppose the statement is true for a $n\ge 7$. Then, since $n\ge 7\ge 5$, you find
$$30-2^n\le 0$$
and
$$30(n+1)<2^n+110+30=2^{n+1}+110+30-2^n<2^{n+1}+110$$
